# Can't seem to insert a guid (userID) into table!

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I'm creating a web project for one of my uni modules using Visual studio 2010. 
I'm using asp.net membership and have all of my sql-server tables set up correctly (I'm pretty sure).

I have a form that I have created myself that inserts into the database using sqlDataSource.insert(). I had some problems initially with not being able to insert any data into the table at all, but I have cleared that up.

My problem now is that I need to insert the currently logged in user's userID into one of the columns of the table. But every time I hit the submit button, I am told I cannot insert null values in the userID column.

I can retrieve the userID using this snippet:

```
    Dim userID As String
    Dim memUser As MembershipUser
    memUser = Membership.GetUser()
    userID = memUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString()
    e.Command.Parameters(0).Value = userID
```

This is the code behind for the page:

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

'Dim userID As Guid = CType(memUser.ProviderUserKey, Guid)



Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Dim UserID As Guid = CType(Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey, Guid)
    'memUser = Membership.GetUser()
    Dim userID As Guid


    Dim memUser As MembershipUser
    memUser = Membership.GetUser()
    userID = memUser.ProviderUserKey

    If IsPostBack() Then
        Session.Add("UserID", userID)
    Else
        userID = Session("UserID")
    End If

    TextBox1.Text = userID.ToString


End Sub
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selecting
    e.Command.Parameters(0).Value = userID

End Sub
Protected Sub buttonInsertCitation_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles buttonInsertCitation.Click


    SqlDataSource1.Insert()
End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see it is a bit of a mess, I've been frantically trying different variations, as I need to catch up a little with other uni modules.

Here is my SQLDataSource from the .aspx page, The controlparameters work fine for the other data I am inserting. maybe the `<asp:parameter name="userID" />` is wrong?

```
<InsertParameters>
        <asp:parameter name="userID" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textNotes" Name="notes" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textEssayTitle" Name="essayTitle" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="radioIsPrivate" Name="isPrivate" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dropPaperID" Name="paperID" PropertyName="Text" />
</InsertParameters>
```

I'm relatively new to vb, and I come from a html & css background.

Comment: First, what is your table structure? Next use Profiler to find out exactly what SQl is being sent. Then we can help you see what is wrong with what is being created.

Comment: `citationID = int, dateAdded = datetime, notes = ntext, essayTitle = varchar(128), isPrivate = bit, paperID = int, userID = uniqueidentifier` (is there a better way to show the structure than this in stackoverflow comments?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the ASP.NET membership providers, you don't need to worry about performing any sql.

Comment: The form I have created is inserted to one of my own tables. The user is able to submit citations they have made, and I need to be able to record their userID in the record being created.